# how to let user pick directory in NSIS

Tags: nsis

I have a NSI installer for windows, the full source is here: https://github.com/huggle/huggle3-qt-lx/blob/master/windows/Huggle.nsi

I can't find anywhere how to make possible to ask user where they want to install the software. Default location is Program Files and that is writable by admins only, so now it requires to be started as administrator even for installing something that could be located anywhere (all libraries are in same folder as executable), the application doesn't require administrator rights for it to run.

How do I make it possible to ask user where they want to install, and elevate permissions of installer in case they decide to use restricted folder?

Answer (score 0):

You already have `!insertmacro MUI_PAGE_DIRECTORY` in that script.

NSIS does not really support delayed UAC elevation. It looks to me like the rest of the script is doing a per-user install so you should just use `InstallDir "$LocalAppdata\Programs\MyApp"`...